I am getting an error while importing Google AI API SDK
I am working on a chrome extension where I need to call the Google AI API. When I try importing the SDK in my content.js using
import { GoogleGenerativeAI } from "@google/generative-ai";

I get an error
Uncaught SyntaxError: cannot use import outside a module

The question is how can I import the SDK in my extension which is completely client side. Is there any other way to deliver the SDK alongwith the extension?

The only way to import npm modules is to use a bundler like webpack.
